# vim Segmentation fault (core dumped) during ctrl-space installation

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

vim now fail to load and crashes after ctrl-space plugin installation.

Initially, `strace vim` indicates `.viminfo` file permission issue.  Even after `chmod` to 777, the issue persists.

```
$ vim
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$strace vim
munmap(0xb7486000, 4096)                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, {0x8156bd0, [], SA_STACK|SA_SIGINFO}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [SEGV], [SEGV], 8) = 0
kill(12971, SIGSEGV)                    = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 26 2014 21:03:41)
Included patches: 1-417
Compiled by pocheng@hangtuah
Normal version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

On ubuntu 12.04 32-bit desktop.

Do I have to recompile vim?

Comment: Delete ctrl-space entry from .vimrc and bundle directory.  Recompiled vim.  Resolved the issue.  Certainly something is not right with ctrl-space.

Answer (score 1):

Get a backtrace from the segfaulting vim and report it to the vim_dev (vim-dev@vim.org) Mailinglist. Also try with the latest Vim version, before reporting that error. See also the [faq](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.6)